# Ignoring folders when copying/pasting from explorer

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

My problem is how to ignore a folder or directory when copying from explorer and pasting it from clipboard, my code is okay when you only copy a file from explorer but when copy both files and folder, I get an **System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file**. thanks

```
 Private Sub mnuPaste_Click(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs)     Handles mnuPaste.Click
        '//if clipboard has a file drop list, paste the names of all files in this list in a datagridview
        If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList Then
            Dim fileDropList As Specialized.StringCollection
            fileDropList = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetFileDropList()
            For Each fileName As String In fileDropList
                If strAllowedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower()) Then
                    InsertToList(fileName)
                Else
                    blnNotAllowed = True
                End If
            Next
            If blnNotAllowed = True Then
                MsgBox("Some of the files you paste is not supported, Please check the Help Contents for the list supported files.")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Clipboard does not contain a file drop list", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation And MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: `If File.Exists(fileName) = False Then Continue For`?

Comment: thanks @VisualVincent, works great